# Form element remains invalid after it has been updated in controller in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/766/embedded/result/). When the field is on focus, a drop down box appears. When you click on an element within the dropdown box, the value is updated in the model (`categoryFilter`) and the model's state is updated from `ng-invalid` to `ng-valid`. When you remove the value, it's back to `ng-invalid`, when you go select a value again, it's back to `ng-valid`. In other words, it works perfect.

I made this fiddle according to my code. Although my code (controller + form) is exactly the same, for some reason after I select an item, erase it and selects an item again, the field remains `ng-invalid`. You can check this for yourself if you [**go here**](http://www.workoutcrowd.com/users/20/name+lastlkj) and select a value, remove and select it again. You'll see the state remains `ng-invalid` although the form + controller is the same. Where's the problem?

```
desktop.controller('StartClubModalController', function ($scope,$http,$modalInstance) {


    $scope.$watch('categoryFilter', function(value) {
        angular.element(categoryFilter).val(value);
    });

    $scope.categories = [{"Category":{"id":"6","category":"Community"}},{"Category":{"id":"4","category":"Competitions"}},{"Category":{"id":"5","category":"Crossfit"}},{"Category":{"id":"2","category":"Fitness"}},{"Category":{"id":"3","category":"Sport"}},{"Category":{"id":"1","category":"Workout"}}];

    $scope.categoryDropDownClickEvent = function(value) {                   
        $scope.categoryFilter = value;
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, its not good practice to manipulate with DOM into controller. All DOM manipulation/update implement into directive. Directives are only place where you should write jQuery code while using AngularJS.

Secondly, the `categoryFilter` is `ng-model` so you don't need to use `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch('categoryFilter', function(value) {
        angular.element(categoryFilter).val(value);
    });
```

Remove it. *(BTW, this is advantage of Angular)*

On any change `categoryFilter` should update automatically.

See fixed Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/767/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed true I should put it in a directive. That was my plan afterwards. 
Regarding removing the `watch`, when i removed it it causes the model not be updated after the second time you select an item. This only happens in my app, not in fiddle although the code is the same :S. I think the problem my be correlated to this. Please check [here](http://www.workoutcrowd.com/users/20/name+lastlkj) and select something, remove and try to select it again. It's driving me insane

Comment: Strange, the only one way is to start disable imports on your site

Comment: Did you try last stable version 1.2.0-rc.3 for Angular?

Comment: Thanks, i guess that's the only solution... Im using [this angular solution for lazy loading](http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/). Do you reckon the problem might be there? Knowing so will narrow it down a lot :)

Comment: just now, same problem :(

Comment: Maybe i'll just remove it and do it the regular way. Implementing lazy loading made the whole thing so much more complicated...